# scala binary vs scala full version convention

Tags: scala

I am readying the following sbt page:
https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Cross-Build.html#Cross-building

But i find the documentation not that great, and would like to clarify something which i think i understand but is not made explicit in the doc.

What is the convention for :

> `CrossVersion.binary (_<scala-binary-version>)`

> `CrossVersion.full (_<scala-version>)`

In other words i want a simple example of

`_<scala-binary-version>`

and of

_

is it :

1. Binary Version example 2.12
2. Scala version example 2.12.12

Is that the difference between a binary version and the scala version, where the later would include the compiler access and what not ?

## EDIT1

The following example is given in the page:

These are equivalent:

```
"a" %% "b" % "1.0"
("a" % "b" % "1.0").cross(CrossVersion.binary)
```

This overrides the defaults to always use the full Scala version instead of the binary Scala version:

```
("a" % "b" % "1.0").cross(CrossVersion.full)
```

I only understand what is meant is the second statement, because i have been using the first and know what it does. But it is a guess, and i am just looking for an explicit confirmation with an example, which i believe could benefit any new scala dev in their journey.

Comment: I know you already answer something similar that I asked and I understood your answer well. I just find the documentation not clear enough. I want to someone to confirm what is the difference between the two statement scala version and scala binary version and have an example for each that is all

Comment: I'll be happy to accept that as the official answer. This could help other. Otherwise, thank you for the authoritative confirmation. As always, very helpful @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So `2.12.12` is a full version *(as well as a patch version)* and `2.12` is a binary version.

Binary versions are useful because libraries compiled using a different but binary compatible version can be used in your project without any problems. For example, if you are using **Scala** `2.13.3` you can use a library that was compiled using `2.13.0` or `2.13.4` but not one compiled using `2.12.12`.
The full version is useful for things that access the underlying compiler API which doesn't retain binary compatibility, for example, compiler plugins like the **kind projector**.

BTW, just for fun, `2.13.0-RC1` is another full version but not a patch version.